# How do I populate a StructuredProperty from a dict?

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

There is no `populate` method on `StructuredProperty` (like the one on `ndb.Model`) so how do I populate those fields from a dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still `populate` the `StructuredProperty`.

If you have models like this:

```
class A(ndb.Model):
  value = ndb.IntegerProperty()

class B(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  a = ndb.StructuredProperty(A)
```

The following will populate the properties of both:

```
my_dict = {"name":"my name", "a":{"value":1}}
b = B()
b.populate(**my_dict)
```

You can also call `populate` on the property:

```
my_dict = {"value":1}
b = B()
b.a = A()
b.a.populate(**my_dict)
```

Note that what is returned by the getter is not the `StructuredProperty` instance. It is an instance of `A`. So calling `populate` works.